# computer name in web.config

Tags: wcf

My App is silverlight with WCF Service.

During development I use `http://localhost/WCFService/Service1.svc` on the client config but for some reasons the localhost doesn't work even though the service is on the same box.
When I change it to computer name it works.

How can I have something like `http://[ComputerName]/WCFService/Service1.svc` in web.config so that after deployment to different machines it dynamically get's the computer name.

Answer (score 0):

quite strange localhost must get resolved, anyway you may try

`http://127.0.0.1/WCFService/Service1.svc`

double check that your service is running on local machine

Comment: My scenario is that the silverlight app would be accessed from outside this machine also. So, I can't have localhost or 127.0.0.1 in the web.config.
http://ipaddress/silverlightclient/default.aspx